# How to get all sibling elements of td into an array

Tags: jquery

I have a table with several columns. The first column of the table contains buttons with a specific id.
I want when the user clicks the button of one row to get an array with all the values for this specific row.

I am doing something like this:

```
$("#"+id).closest('td').siblings().text()
```

But this returns a string with all the values together. How can I return an array, which will have the values separated with commas?

```
**EDIT**
```

The table is created automatically using DataTables jquery plugin and jquery functionality.
On page load my html structure looks like this:

```
<table id="example">
  <thead id="table_head">
  </thead>
</table>
```

Then the table is populated with data coming from Django. The button element looks like this:

```
edit_btn = '<button id="' + row_id + '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm _edit_save_btn" style="background-color:#a7a3a3;border-color:#a7a3a3">Edit</button>'
```

Comment: Please show your HTML as well.

Comment: This is still hard to understand. Show the HTML code generated for this entire td, otherwise it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map().get()`:

```
var arr = $("#"+id).closest('td').siblings().map(function(){
   return this.textContent;
}).get();
// outputs ["text1", "text2",.......n]
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I guess I can use the same functions (map and get to get also the name of the table's columns, right?)